# How to handle ManipulationCompleted event in windows phone 8?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I have the following code but it is not working can anyone suggest me what changes i need to do in order to making it working .

```
Mainscroll.ManipulationCompleted += new EventHandler<System.Windows.Input.ManipulationCompletedEventArgs>(Mainscroll_completed);
 private void Mainscroll_completed(object sender, System.Windows.Input.ManipulationCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            UIElement target = sender as UIElement;
            target.AddHandler(UIElement.ManipulationCompletedEvent, new EventHandler(layoutroot), true);
           // throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        private void layoutroot(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("done");
        }
```

Comment: It's completely unclear what are you trying to achieve and what's not working. And why are you calling `target.AddHandler...`?

Comment: When we are scrolling i want to handle the event at the end of the scroll. I want to know which scroll event is handle when i reach the end of the scroll so that i can handle Scollviewer's ManipulationCompleted event. I am using these code for windows 8 phone and i have read in net that if ManipulationCompleted doesn't work then we have to use the target.Addhandler.

Answer (score 0):

Replace this line:

```
Mainscroll.ManipulationCompleted += 
    new EventHandler<System.Windows.Input.ManipulationCompletedEventArgs>(Mainscroll_completed);
```

with this line:

```
this.Mainscroll.AddHandler(
    Pivot.ManipulationCompletedEvent, 
    new EventHandler<ManipulationCompletedEventArgs>(Mainscroll_completed), true);
```

and remove:

```
target.AddHandler(UIElement.ManipulationCompletedEvent......
```